# How do I temporarily remove grub from mbr?

Tags: bootloader

I have a dual-boot system with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7.  Windows 7 has recently released an update that won't install due to grub.  I want to restore the windows bootloader so it can install this update, and then go back to grub.  I **don't** want to uninstall windows or ubuntu.  How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure about Win7 (hence this in comment instead of an answer) but XP had an option on the install CD to repair the MBR.  This would reset to single boot, Windows only (don't know for certain it would fix Vista or 7, or that they have this), allowing you to install your update; once done, you can run the GRUB repair on the Ubuntu DVD/USB.  Be VERY careful in selecting the correct partitions in these two operations...

Comment: @ZeissIkon: Windows 7 still has the same option, but the procedure to reach the rescue environment is somewhat different.